# Does Nuget Restore Install Latest Version?

Tags: jenkins, nuget

Ok, our team is using Nuget.exe with a *restore* option and I have reason to think that we may be automatically getting the latest version.  I've been hunting around for documentation (lots of Googling) and I see this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#constraining-upgrade-versions

And in that page it has a specific call out:

> By default, reinstalling or updating a package *always* installs the
> latest version available from the package source. (Emphasis in the original)

So given that I was wondering if someone can confirm whether or not Nuget.exe -restore *does not* automatically grab the latest version.

It appears to be NuGet.exe 4.3.0 and the command line is something like `c:\buildagent\tools\Nuget.CommandLine.4.3.0\tools\Nuget.exe restore <pathToSlnFile> -NoCache`

The build is done via Jenkins if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you refer to the package version that being restored
For managing and restoring specific version you can use packages.config and define a version or a range of versions as seen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#references-in-project-files-packagereference

Comment: If you don't specify a version (or range of versions) does Nuget restore automatically use the latest version?  That's what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#examples 
"Without a version or version range, NuGet 2.8.x and earlier chooses the latest available package version when resolving a dependency, whereas NuGet 3.x and later chooses the lowest package version."